# Generate HTML file in c# on click button

Tags: c#, html

How can i create HTML file on submit button click in c#,I don't know any syntax about this ,Please suggest me How to create Html page in C#

Comment: The answer is read a tutorial

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use Generic Handler in web application ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353260/ASP-NET-Advanced-Generic-Handler-ASHX )...

Comment: Link only answers are bad, the link may break and your answer will be useless. Also, there is nothing in the question to suggest the OP is using ASP.Net - they may be, but you should clarify that with comments before making such assumptions with an answer

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at some beginner tutorials:

- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials

Comment: what makes you think he is creating asp.net app ? it might be windows forms or WPF

Comment: Nothing indeed. But the question is not clear and he seems to be a beginner, so I am offering something.

Comment: +1 for helping the guy, better yet , ask for his specific needs rather than a pointer in the "wrong" direction :)

Comment: The best way to help the OP in this case is to **comment** and ask for them to fix their question with additional information. Not take a guess at what they want and then provide a link-only answer. Even with a good question, this answer is poor. If you want to just link to a tutorial, then a comment is the place for that